# Lower Level Key Capture Method on macOS with Swift

Tags: swift, macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a more reliable or lower level method for capturing key events. Currently I am using NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask but it misses some key combinations that are reserved for system functions, such as CMD+Space, for instance. Is there another way to more reliably and preferably with lower latency capture keyboard events. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try an event tap?

Comment: I am looking for a system wide key trap, not sure if that would work.